# Difference Between Creating A Local Branch With And Without '-b'

Tags: git

I have a situation where I didn't understand the updation how it happens internally.

I have 2 remote branches:

```
master
dev
```

Now, I want to create 3 local branches out of dev.

Command 1:

```
git checkout dev
```

command 2:

```
git checkout -b "Us1DevBranch" origin/dev
```

command 3:

```
git checkout -b "Us2DevBranch" origin/dev
```

When a `git branch` command is executed I have,

```
dev
Us1DevBranch
Us2DevBranch
```

**Scenario**:- 
After 5 days I picked a branch Us1DevBranch and starting adding some files into this branch. In these 5 days, lets suppose 5 modifications were made to the remote dev branch and I wanted to take an update.

Now when I did, `git pull origin dev` it affected only my local `dev` branch. The other 2 branches `Us1DevBranch & Us2DevBranch` didn't get updated.

**Questions**:-

1) What I read in the documentation and other discussion forum is that, git pull internally does a git fetch and then a git merge to the local branches created out of that branch. But then why the other 2 branches didn't get updated!

2) I was under the impression that checking out a branch with `-b` option is just to give a different local name to the branch & everything else is same. But there is something much more than that, as when I did `git pull`, only the branch created out of the option `git checkout dev` got affected, not the other branches! Why is it so?

Comment: You might have gotten a message when next you checked out `Us1DevBranch`: "Your branch and 'origin/dev' have diverged, and have 1 and 5 different commits, respectively." When you see that it means you need to take some action to update the local branch (usually a `merge` or a `rebase`).

Comment: True..but my question is git pull internally does fetch+merge...so the merge operation is implicitly happening...hence I thought it would update this brnch as well..

Comment: `git pull` only merges into the *current branch*. Other branches (i.e., branches that are not currently checked out) cannot be merged because you can only resolve merge conflicts in the current working tree.

Comment: @trentcl , got it....I didn't understnd wat 'git pull --all' does,,,, I mean if say dere are 3 brnches out of dev,,, dev1, dev2 & dev3. If I m inside dev3 and do either "git pull origin dev" or "git pull --all"...It affects only dev3. Other 2 branches r not updated yet even for git pull --all....then wat is the use of --all

Comment: `--all` says to fetch from all remotes. It's analogous to (I think) `git fetch --all; git merge origin/dev`.
`git pull` really doesn't do much. You might find it informative to read the answers and comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following command:

```
git checkout dev
```

just doing **one** job: It changes your current branch to *dev*; It **does not create any branch named *dev***! you can do `git checkout dev` because you already have it there in your local branch as a result of **cloning** your remote branch which has a *dev* branch.

BUT

```
git checkout -b "Us1DevBranch" origin/dev
```

does **three** jobs:

1. It creates a branch, named *Us1DevBranch*
2. It checks out to that branch (i.e. changes your current branch to newly created *Us1DevBranch* branch
3. It setup this local branch to track remote *origin/dev* branch (i.e. every time you are on this branch and do `git fetch`, `git pull`, `git push` it will update against remote *origin/dev* branch). Without this last arg you need to specify *remote* and *branch* every time you `git fetch`, `git pull`, `git push` i.e `git pull origin dev` to update your local branch with remote dev for example.

So `git checkout -b "Us1DevBranch"` is equal to `git branch "Us1DevBranch"` + `git checkout "Us1DevBranch"` and the last parameter of your command `origin/dev` will setup tracking for this newly created branch.

Finally you can manually setup tracking for your already existing branches like *dev* through:

```
git branch -u origin/dev dev
```

and there is no need to setup tracking for *master* because it will automatically sets up to track *origin/master* as a result of cloning.

You can always check tracking information of branches (i.e My local branches track which remote brach?) by the following command:

```
git branch -vv
```

Comment: Ya u r rite, I am able to do 'git checkout dev', because iy came as parT of my cloning. My Bad! But I have 1 question still.. When I am in the branch 'Us1DevBranch' and I run the command, 'git pull origin dev', it didn't update the current branch Us1DevBranch, only the dev local got affected,, not the Us1DevBranch even though this branch was created out of Dev..

Comment: That the *Us1DevBranch* created out of *Dev* branch does not mean anything speciall to their relations with remote branches. *Us1DevBranch* simply contains all the commits of dev branch to this point of divergence. when you run `git pull origin dev` in *Us1DevBranch* branch you simply tell git that apply all changes from *remote dev branch* to this branch that i am currently on and it should not affect local dev atall. have a look at `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` and see what you can found out of it.

Answer (score 3):

1) When you create a new branch, it's completely distinct from that point in time. You'll have to manually update all those branches as well.

2) if you just want to give it a different name and keep everything else the same:

```
git branch -m newbranchname
```

Comment: (1) but dev got updated when I did a pull. And what does manually update mean, I thought git pull(git fetch + git merge) is the updation that happens to the local branch      (2) What is the difference in the 2 syntax

Answer (score 1):

Aswering the title question. The '-b' option passed to the `git checkout` is to create a new branch. It's used when you want to create and checkout to the new branch in one line.

Now if you want to fetch/pull all your branches, you could use `git fetch --all` or `git remote update`, this are equivalent. Or even `git push --all`.